# Determining If a Method needs to be static or private or non static

Tags: java

I am having trouble in determining whether a method should be static or private. I have asked different people but the concept behind when to use both does not stick. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: If it requires state (i.e. access to one or more non-static fields) in order to return a result then it should not be static. If it does not require state, it should be static. With regards to access modifier (public/private/etc.), it should be the lowest that is required to fulfill its purpose. Start at private and work up.

Comment: You understand that static means you don’t have to invoke `new` on the object first to use it?

Comment: 'static' means a single value across all instances of an object.  Not having it means you'll have a value unique to each instance of an object. - this is why the comment just above makes sense.  Since a 'static' variable isn't attached to a particular instance of an object, you don't need to create an object to be able to access it.

Comment: 'private' just determines if code outside the object can access that thing (member variable, static variable, method, etc.) . The two concepts are independent. - so all four combinations might be the right thing in a particular case

Comment: Methods that need to be polymorphic also can't be static (and of course not private). Even if they don't deal with state: You can't override a static method.

Comment: there are a lot of great answers to this question on stackoverflow already. have you tried searching around? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=static+vs+private+java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` and `static` are two different concepts that do not directly compare.

`static` means that the method or variable is tied to the class, not to an instance of the class. When you access a static method or variable, you can access it by using the class name. Let's say your Banana class has a static method `static String fruitName()`, then you can call it like this: `Banana.fruitName()`. You don't need a specific `Banana`, but just the class.

Let's say instead that you have a non-static method like `void peel()` that modifies the state of a `Banana` object and sets `peeled = true`. In that case you **cannot** call `Banana.peel()`, because you need to `peel` a specific `Banana`. Like this:

```
Banana niceBanana = new Banana();
niceBanana.peel();
```

`private` is a different concept: it is a visibility modifier. It simply indicates that the thing is only accessible from within the class.
So if your `Banana` class is like this:

```
class Banana {
  private int weight;
}
```

Then, you will able to access the `weight` variable only inside the `Banana` class. The same goes for other things marked as private, like methods, classes.